Can i change this formula to tracks from a start and finish date instead of a list of dates in a column?
New to all this, so i apologize in advance for my ignorance. I have a calendar that tracks people's leave/TAD time based on dates. Currently I have the dates listed in series in a single column labled "date" on the LEAVE tab. Can i switch this to work with just a simple "start date" and end date" I am trying to reduce the overwhelming number of lines on the LEAVE tab.
my sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ektARrWjd108GVnx5OLYtNqI9UB1V9KXLIiexw_0FgI/edit?usp=sharing
current formula:
=if($B5 <> "", iferror(vlookup(vlookup($B5&D$4,LEAVE!$A:$F,6,false),Lookups!$A:$B,2,false),""),"")

I have tried several things from google/youtube but i lack the knowledge required to implement them properly.

Apologize. Should be fixed now.      https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ektARrWjd108GVnx5OLYtNqI9UB1V9KXLIiexw_0FgI/edit?usp=sharing


delete Calendar!B1
delete everything in range Calendar!D2:AH4
paste this in Calendar!D3


=LET(x, SEQUENCE(1, EOMONTH(C2&B2, 0)-EOMONTH(C2&B2, -1), EOMONTH(C2&B2, -1)+1), {x;x})


delete everything in range Calendar!A5:C
paste this in Calendar!A5


=SORT(Employees!A5:C, 2, 1)


delete everything in range Employees!F5:H
paste this in Employees!F5


=BYCOL({"<=", ">"}, LAMBDA(q, BYROW(B5:INDEX(B:B, MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))), LAMBDA(b, LET(w, TOCOL(LET(d, LEAVE!D3:INDEX(LEAVE!D:D, MAX(ROW(LEAVE!D:D)*(LEAVE!D:D<>""))), FILTER(BYROW(d, LAMBDA(x, IF(ISEVEN(ROW(x)),,SEQUENCE(1, OFFSET(x,1,)-x, x)))), INDEX(OFFSET(d,,-2)&OFFSET(d,,-1))="Yes"&b)), 1), COUNTIFS(w, ">="&F2, w, "<="&H2, w, q&NOW()))))))


paste this in Employees!H5


=INDEX(IF(B5:B<>"", E5:E-F5:F-G5:G, ))


delete everything in range Lookups!F1:F12
delete entire column E in LEAVE sheet
on LEAVE sheet un-filter (disable filtered view) columns C, D, E, F and delete everything in range LEAVE!C3:F
paste this in LEAVE!C3


=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(SPLIT("×BLISS, THOMAS¤45418¤DETACHMENT×BLISS, THOMAS¤45457¤×BODE, WILLIAM¤45523¤ROUTINE LEAVE×BODE, WILLIAM¤45528¤×BYNUM, KAYLA¤45475¤ROUTINE LEAVE×BYNUM, KAYLA¤45477¤×BYNUM, KAYLA¤45493¤ROUTINE LEAVE×BYNUM, KAYLA¤45506¤×DAVIS, WILLIAMS¤45439¤ROUTINE LEAVE×DAVIS, WILLIAMS¤45474¤×DONOVAN, JOSEPH¤45467¤ROUTINE LEAVE×DONOVAN, JOSEPH¤45476¤×GOEINS, MICHAEL¤45451¤ROUTINE LEAVE×GOEINS, MICHAEL¤45460¤×GOEINS, MICHAEL¤45497¤ROUTINE LEAVE×GOEINS, MICHAEL¤45503¤×HICKS, ALEXANDER¤45420¤ROUTINE LEAVE×HICKS, ALEXANDER¤45427¤×JAMES, JASON¤45474¤ROUTINE LEAVE×JAMES, JASON¤45480¤×JENNISON, JOSHUA¤45484¤ROUTINE LEAVE×JENNISON, JOSHUA¤45492¤×JONES, JEVON¤45463¤ROUTINE LEAVE×JONES, JEVON¤45477¤×KIM, JEREMY¤45475¤ROUTINE LEAVE×KIM, JEREMY¤45492¤×LARA, BLAINE¤45451¤ROUTINE LEAVE×LARA, BLAINE¤45458¤×LI, TONY¤45404¤ROUTINE LEAVE×LI, TONY¤45421¤×LIRA, CYRILLE¤45417¤DETACHMENT×LIRA, CYRILLE¤45458¤×LLOYD, JEROME¤45442¤ROUTINE LEAVE×LLOYD, JEROME¤45447¤×LOMBARD, ETHAN¤45418¤ROUTINE LEAVE×LOMBARD, ETHAN¤45432¤×LOMBARD, ETHAN¤45451¤DETACHMENT×LOMBARD, ETHAN¤45487¤×MCGREGOR, DANIEL¤45418¤DETACHMENT×MCGREGOR, DANIEL¤45487¤×MAHER, BRANDON¤45431¤ROUTINE LEAVE×MAHER, BRANDON¤45435¤×MAHER, BRANDON¤45445¤ROUTINE LEAVE×MAHER, BRANDON¤45453¤×MONCREIF, BASIL¤45426¤ROUTINE LEAVE×MONCREIF, BASIL¤45433¤×MOORE, ANTHONY¤45425¤ROUTINE LEAVE×MOORE, ANTHONY¤45429¤×ORLOVA, IRINA¤45415¤ROUTINE LEAVE×ORLOVA, IRINA¤45429¤×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45401¤ROUTINE LEAVE×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45420¤×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45422¤ROUTINE LEAVE×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45440¤×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45451¤DETACHMENT×PAUL, JOSEPH¤45487¤×PICOTT, JERRY¤45475¤ROUTINE LEAVE×PICOTT, JERRY¤45477¤×PICOTT, JERRY¤45493¤ROUTINE LEAVE×PICOTT, JERRY¤45506¤×RAHRIG, WILLIAM¤45457¤ROUTINE LEAVE×RAHRIG, WILLIAM¤45472¤×ROBERTS, BRANDON¤45463¤ROUTINE LEAVE×ROBERTS, BRANDON¤45466¤×SHARIF, YAMINAH¤45470¤ROUTINE LEAVE×SHARIF, YAMINAH¤45477¤×SPRIGGS, LAINE¤45431¤ROUTINE LEAVE×SPRIGGS, LAINE¤45432¤×STROMAN, CODY¤45415¤ROUTINE LEAVE×STROMAN, CODY¤45419¤×TAYLOR, ILLIAM¤45431¤ROUTINE LEAVE×TAYLOR, ILLIAM¤45432¤×UMIKOROJONES, PHILOMINA¤45430¤ROUTINE LEAVE×UMIKOROJONES, PHILOMINA¤45434¤×UMIKOROJONES, PHILOMINA¤45451¤ROUTINE LEAVE×UMIKOROJONES, PHILOMINA¤45455¤×WILLIAMS, ISLEY¤45449¤ROUTINE LEAVE×WILLIAMS, ISLEY¤45453¤×WILLIAMS, ISLEY¤45455¤ROUTINE LEAVE×WILLIAMS, ISLEY¤45458¤", "×")), "¤"))


select range LEAVE!C3:F and press CTRL+C then CTRL+SHIFT+V
now you can add more data below if needed in this fashion:

NAME + startDATE + TYPE as usually
NAME + (endDATE+plus1day) + empty TYPE (acts as "BACK")
names always in pairs even if date is just one day


delete everything in range LEAVE!A3:B
paste this in LEAVE!A3


=INDEX(IF((C3:C<>"")*(D3:D<>""), {C3:C&D3:D, IFNA(VLOOKUP(E3:E, Lookups!A:C, 3, 0))}, ))


delete everything in range Calendar!D5:AH
paste this in Calendar!D5


=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(B5:INDEX(B:B, MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>"")))&D4:4, SORT(LEAVE!A:E), 5, 1), Lookups!A:B, 2, 0)))


enjoy

